# What is the probability of new record occurs every time in uniform distribution

Tags: probability

let $U(n) = \max(U_1,......U_n)$ where each $U_i$ has a
uniform distribution on $[0; 1]$.What is the probability that $U_{n+1}$ will become a new current record at the time?

Do I understand it correctly that it is asking about the probability $U(n+1)$ is bigger than any number occurred before? Someone told me that the probability is $1$. But I disagree. Because $U(n+1)$ can definitely be smaller the some numbers occurred before. 
Can any one please help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not $1$, for the reason you say.

Have $U_j \leq z$ for all $j \in [1,n]$ with probability $z^{n}$, since this happens if and only if each individual (presumed independent) $U_i < z$.

Therefore the maximum is $U_{n+1}$ with probability $$\int_0^1 u_{n+1}^{n} d u_{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+1}$$

Comment: Hi where can I get more details of the material related to this question? Could you please provide some website that I can read more about it? Because I don't really understand it.

Comment: @nicole Any first course in probability should cover the required background. I've used http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~grg/books/probint.html in the past.